# Reading corrupt file, segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, bash

I run my program by passing it a bunch of directories like this:

```
./myprogram *
```

Each directory is a separate set of files that I am parsing for data which I then create into a spreadsheet. Each directory is a different row of the spreadsheet. I want to only put reliable data in the spreadsheet and so if an entry is missing I leave it out. It seems to work well on most of the directories but on some directories I get a segmentation fault during one of my parse functions.

I have noticed that every file that results in a segmentation fault is unopenable with gedit. It gives this error:

gedit has not been able to detect the character coding.
Please check that you are not trying to open a binary file.
Select a character coding from the menu and try again.

However, I am able to display the file by use the cat or tail commands.

The specific function that results in the segmentation fault is the fscanf function below, that I use to read a single line at a time. (increasing the size of the buffers did not help)

```
 char *line = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
 char *garbage = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
 while(!feof(infile) )
 {
     fscanf(infile,"%[^\n]%[\n]",line,garbage);
     //parse the line
 }
```

Does anyone know why the file may be unopenable with gedit? Is it corrupted? Is there a way I can return an error code in my parse function instead of seg faulting?

Comment: Why is your program crashing? What is the failure? Have you looked at the backtrace/used a debugger? That doesn't look like `gedit` can't open it more like `gedit` doesn't like it but I would hope you could force it. If you use `cat -A file` does every other character look like `^@`? Because that would make it a UTF-16 file.

Comment: That's a weird way of detecting end of file by the way.

Comment: Don't use fscanf.  1000 bytes isn't a big buffer.  This would crash if you overran the buffer because you ran it on a file that doesn't contain a \n.  Use fread, and parse the buffer.

Comment: @Etan, when I ran the cat -A there was a giant block of ^@ characters, but the rest of the file was fine.

Comment: @Matt, do you have an easier way to read a line at a time, or is there was way to prevent overflow? Also, I wrote this before I knew feof existed, so I will update that.

Comment: That's the problem. That's a giant block of `NUL` bytes. And is probably what's blowing up your buffers like Matt indicated.

Comment: And don't use feof(), at least not this way.

Comment: @wildplasser, do you have a recommendation how to do this? Having a single line was quite convenient since a lot of the data I'm reading is like   `garbage    variable:   5   garbage \n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a buffer overrun in `fscanf()`.  This is probably causing the program to write past the end of the array, overwrite a pointer somewhere, and crash.

Your options are:

Read a line into an input buffer with `fgets()` and parse it with `sscanf()` if necessary, probably what you want, or

Tell `fscanf()` the sizes of the buffers, e.g. `fscanf( infile, " %999[^\n]%*[\n]", line );`

Additionally, you almost never want `while (!feof(infile))`.  This will stop when it reads *past* end-of-file.

So you should really change this to:

```
static const size_t LINE_LEN = 1000;
while (fgets( line, LINE_LEN, infile ))
  /* Do stuff with line. */
```

Or

```
while ( 1 == fscanf( infile, " %999[^\n]%*[\n]", line ) )
  /* Do stuff with line. */
```